# How to make the container header fixed and not scroll with the content?

Tags: html, css

How to keep the container header at the top of the container all the time while the content in the background is scrollable?

Header and content need to be in one container.

Without jQuery or JS please.

```css
.contentContainer {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.scrollContainer {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid
}

.scrollContainer_header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.scrollable_content {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="contentContainer">
    Content #1
  </div>
  <div class="scrollContainer">
    <div class="scrollContainer_header">
      HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="scrollable_content">
      LOOOOONG SCROLLABLE CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentContainer">
    Content #2
  </div>
</div>
```

[link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qf8r6abL/)

Answer (score 2):

**Use    `position: sticky;`**(see fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/qf8r6abL/13/)

```
.scrollContainer_header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```css
.contentContainer{
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.scrollContainer{
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid
}
.scrollContainer_header{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
.scrollable_content{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="contentContainer">
  Content #1 
  </div>
  <div class="scrollContainer">
    <div class="scrollContainer_header">
      HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="scrollable_content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. At multis se probavit. Odium autem et invidiam facile vitabis. Post enim Chrysippum eum non sane est disputatum. Id et fieri posse et saepe esse factum et ad voluptates percipiendas maxime pertinere. At tu eadem ista dic in iudicio aut, si coronam times, dic in senatu. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. Eadem nunc mea adversum te oratio est.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. At multis se probavit. Odium autem et invidiam facile vitabis. Post enim Chrysippum eum non sane est disputatum. Id et fieri posse et saepe esse factum et ad voluptates percipiendas maxime pertinere. At tu eadem ista dic in iudicio aut, si coronam times, dic in senatu. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. Eadem nunc mea adversum te oratio est.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. At multis se probavit. Odium autem et invidiam facile vitabis. Post enim Chrysippum eum non sane est disputatum. Id et fieri posse et saepe esse factum et ad voluptates percipiendas maxime pertinere. At tu eadem ista dic in iudicio aut, si coronam times, dic in senatu. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. Eadem nunc mea adversum te oratio est.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. At multis se probavit. Odium autem et invidiam facile vitabis. Post enim Chrysippum eum non sane est disputatum. Id et fieri posse et saepe esse factum et ad voluptates percipiendas maxime pertinere. At tu eadem ista dic in iudicio aut, si coronam times, dic in senatu. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. Eadem nunc mea adversum te oratio est.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. At multis se probavit. Odium autem et invidiam facile vitabis. Post enim Chrysippum eum non sane est disputatum. Id et fieri posse et saepe esse factum et ad voluptates percipiendas maxime pertinere. At tu eadem ista dic in iudicio aut, si coronam times, dic in senatu. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. Eadem nunc mea adversum te oratio est.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. At multis se probavit. Odium autem et invidiam facile vitabis. Post enim Chrysippum eum non sane est disputatum. Id et fieri posse et saepe esse factum et ad voluptates percipiendas maxime pertinere. At tu eadem ista dic in iudicio aut, si coronam times, dic in senatu. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. Eadem nunc mea adversum te oratio est.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. At multis se probavit. Odium autem et invidiam facile vitabis. Post enim Chrysippum eum non sane est disputatum. Id et fieri posse et saepe esse factum et ad voluptates percipiendas maxime pertinere. At tu eadem ista dic in iudicio aut, si coronam times, dic in senatu. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. Eadem nunc mea adversum te oratio est.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentContainer">
    Content #2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an option. `position: sticky` is not supported on IE.

Comment: Use [Stickybits](https://css-tricks.com/stickybits-alternative-position-sticky-polyfills/) as a polyfill for IE.

Comment: Try using position:fixed and top:0px

Comment: Maybe add z-index: 1?

Comment: @JBDouble05 it fixed to top of page

Comment: fixed to nested content see in my answer example

Answer (score 0):

Just change the position of `.scrollContainer_header`class from `absolute` to `sticky`

> .scrollContainer_header{
>   position: sticky;
>   }